# Etsy-like marketplace with Activemerchant? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, activemerchant

I am in the early stages of integrating a vendor marketplace (similar to Etsy, but for a very niche demographic) into an online community.  I envision a platform that allows vendors to sign up and post goods for sale, with all transactions handled through the platform.  Payments would be made from the consumers directly to the Paypal accounts of the vendors.  A processing fee would be incurred for each transaction, with the sum of all fees billed to the vendors at the end of each 30 day period.

I have briefly looked into Activemerchant, though I feel as though it may be the right tool for the job.  Does this sound like something that could be accomplished using Activemerchant?

Answer (score 0):

Activemerchant is simply an API front-end to one of a fairly large number of payment processors. As such, it would surely handle the job of getting money *from* consumers. The funds would normally be deposited into the bank account that you set up with your payment processor.

Then you would need a separate process to pay vendors, which could be handled via one of PayPal's APIs. The two processes (get money from consumer, pay money to vendor) could be disconnected or integrated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://poundpay.com It's geared towards your specific request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, there is a multi vendor solution available that which build on Rails.But i have found various solutions on Core php and ecommerce software like open cart,oscommerce and so on.

Refer [Multi Vendor Shopping Cart Software](http://www.sakthiganesh.com/multi-vendor-shopping-cart-store-scripts)