# Configuring or adapting Spree or another solution to create a multi-vendor, single domain marketplace (similar to etsy) in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree, marketplace

I am trying to create a Rails based multi-vendor e-marketplace, similar to Etsy (but for my specific niche). I did see a similar question at [Etsy-like marketplace with Activemerchant? (Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411675/etsy-like-marketplace-with-activemerchant-rails), but my needs are more than a simple payment processor as that question seems to be discussing.

Vendors would need:

Customer order management system
CMS (e.g. adding & updating products)
Invoicing system
Ability receive payments directly from customers

and the marketplace management would need:

Vendor account management system
Commission invoicing system (% of vendor-to-consumer transactions, invoiced to vendors)

To Refactor my question, given the above information: Are there any currently available solutions that could be adapted to meet my needs, and how difficult it be to make that adaption? I'm currently looking at spree http://spreecommerce.com/tour/backend

Thanks guys, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Also, any commentary on creating a custom solution would be welcome as this indirectly helps to answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, check out Jeff Dutil's work with [Spree Marketplace](https://github.com/jdutil/spree_marketplace) and [Spree Drop Ship](https://github.com/jdutil/spree_drop_ship). With a bit of work for stable releases and customization, they may be able to achieve what you're looking to do.