# Using Spree commerce to create a marketplace solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I am doing research on creating a B2B ecommerce platform similar to Alibaba. My reading and current experience has led me to Spree commerce (since I have built a few apps using RoR before).

Spree looks like an amazing solution but I am really confused by converting the Vanilla Spree app into a marketplace app that could facilitate multiple merchants/sellers.

I have managed to install a standard Spree installation after which I've tried to incorporate [spree_drop_ship](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_drop_ship) and [spree_marketplace](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_marketplace) but this results in numerous dependancy issues. It seems that the latter part of the installation is not maintained anymore and has not been for quite a while.

My question is simply: what is the suggested way to transform Spree into a multivendor marketplace seeing that the original marketplace gems are not maintained anymore?

PS. I have looked at a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140166/configuring-or-adapting-spree-or-another-solution-to-create-a-multi-vendor-sing)

Comment: Did you have a look at Solidus? It's a fork of Spree and it appears to be well maintained, with several extensions available: https://github.com/solidusio/solidus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would recommend going for a custom marketplace solution if your are having time. I’m not saying this just because I run a web application development agency, but because I’m a big fan of Amazon’s business model where they always focus on long-term growth. This is the biz model that I would recommend for every eCommerce marketplace entrepreneur.

There are answers for you http://motivesense.com/multi-vendor-ecommerce-platforms/